# Wordpress profile will allow view but not edit when logged in

Tags: wordpress, profile

Won't work on my system (4.7.10) and replicated on Wordpress sandbox.

I've created a very simple profile: last name & first name.
All fields are expose publicly, searchable, results column etc
Profile ticked "include profile edit links in search results?

Using link from profile "use - listings mode" while logged in as admin.
Ie "http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&gid=14&reset=1"

Search works fine but listing only has view option - no edit

Same when using [civicrm component="profile" gid="68" mode="search" hijack="0"]

Am I missing something?
Same setup works fine on Drupal site

Comment: have you double checked your CMS permissions?

Comment: ?I'm logged in as admin - doesn't that have all permissions

Comment: sorry. i misread that. depends how WP does permissions. Being an 'admin' in Drupal doesn't guarantee all permissions, but being user=1 does.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a WordPress/Civi permissions issue - have you checked at /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1

Comment: “logged in as admin”

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might help get towards an answer if we get some screenshots in here (which I can't do in Comment)

[image]

Having tweaked the Name and Address Profile on wp demo site to do the right things, and if i search at http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&gid=1&reset=1 for 'g' i get the above, and I get a View link but no Edit link.

Pls paste equivalent for drupal

Comment: Of course I don't have access to CMS permissions on demo so can't rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking Pete
Here it is working fine under Drupal
[image]